# Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::store() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\CreateProfileRequest, none given

Tags: php, forms, laravel, request

I have been pulling my hair out with this error for a few hours now but cannot understand why it is doing it. I have done this before on Laravel but it just does not seem to want to work.

This is the method I am trying to get to work:

```
public function store($name, CreateProfileRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::whereName($name)->first();


    $house = new House();
    $house->first_line_address = $request->get('first_line_address');
    $house->city = $request->get('city');
    $house->postcode = $request->get('postcode');

    $user->house()->save($house);

    return redirect('/');

}
```

This is the form I am trying to get the data from:

```
{!! Form::model($user->house, ['route' => 'profile.store']) !!}

    <div class ="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('first_line_address', 'First line of address:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('first_line_address', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('city', 'Town/City:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('postcode', 'Postcode:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('postcode', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Update Profile', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

It is fine until I attempt to store it then I get

Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::store() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\CreateProfileRequest, none given

This is my route:

```
$router->resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
```

| GET|HEAD | profile | profile.index     | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@index
   |            |

|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile/create                                        | profile.create    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@create
   |            |

|        | POST                           | profile                                               | profile.store     | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@store
   |            |

|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile/{profile}                                     | profile.show      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@show
   |            |

|        | GET|HEAD                       | profile/{profile}/edit                                | profile.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@edit
   |            |

|        | PUT                            | profile/{profile}                                     | profile.update    | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update
   |            |

|        | PATCH                          | profile/{profile}                                     |                   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@update
   |            |

|        | DELETE                         | profile/{profile}                                     | profile.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@destroy
   |            |

If anyone thinks of how to get rid of this ridiculous error I will be forever grateful :)

Comment: Try reversing the order of arguments: `store(CreateProfileRequest $request, $name)`

Comment: Thanks! Reversed but ended up with Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::store()

Comment: How does your route look like?

Comment: $router->resource('profile', 'ProfileController');

Comment: @lukasgeiter I had a similar issue. But on changing the order the error went away. Why does the order matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `store()` method of a resource controller/route doesn't take any route parameters. That means Laravel has nothing to pass as `$name` argument. I suppose you're passing the name in the request data itself. If that's the case you can access it with `$request->input('name')`.

Anyways you should remove `$name` from the method signature:

```
public function store(CreateProfileRequest $request)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! You are a life saver aha! I would give you an upvote if it would let me

Answer (score 3):

If you want an instance of `Request` to be available to your controller method, it must be the first argument, followed by other arguments passed via URI. Reverse the methods.

Comment: Just reversed but ended up with Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::store()

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the controller definition and the route?

Comment: Thanks!! Allows for optional parameters, i.e. {user?}